# Google play rejected an update for Intent Redirection Vulnerability

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-security

My application's all the Activity and Service and Receivers are declared as `exported=false`. But Still got the build rejected. If anyone has already faced the issue, please help. Thanks in Advance!

[image]